# Trying to generate a series of unique random numbers

Tags: python, random

Sorry if this is obvious, im pretty new.

Here is the code. 
It should never print the same two things as i understand it, but it sometimes does. The point is that p1 being 1 should prevent p2 from being 1, and if p2 is 1, p2 should run again with the same p1 value, but should generate a new random number. It might be 1 again, but then the function should just keep returning else and running until they're different, right?

```
#Random Test with Exclusion
P1Item = 'Empty'
P2Item = 'Empty'
import random
import time

def P1():
    global P1Item
    global P2Exclusion
    P1Local = random.randint(1,3)
    if P1Local == 1:
        P1Item = 'Candy'
        P2(P1Local)
    elif P1Local == 2:
        P1Item = 'Steak'
        P2(P1Local)
    elif P1Local == 3:
        P1Item = 'Vegetables'
        P2(P1Local)


def P2(A):
    global P2Item
        P2Local = random.randint(1,3)
        if P2Local == 1 and A != 1:
            P2Item = 'Candy'
        elif P2Local == 2 and A != 2:
            P2Item = 'Steak'
        elif P2Local == 3 and A != 3:
        P3Item = 'Vegetables'
        else:
            B = A
            P2(B)

def Test():
    print('Test')
    print('Define')
    P1()
    print(P1Item + ' ' + P2Item)
    time.sleep(1)
    input()
    Test()

Test()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of picking random integers, shuffle a *list* and pick the first two items:

```
import random

choices = ['Candy', 'Steak', 'Vegetables']
random.shuffle(choices)

item1, item2 = choices[:2]
```

Because we shuffled a list of *possible* choices first, then picked the first two, you can guarantee that `item1` and `item2` are never equal to one another.

Using [`random.shuffle()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) leaves the option open to do something with the remaining choices; you only have 1 here, but in a larger set you can continue to pick items that have so far not been picked:

```
choices = list(range(100))
random.shuffle(choices)
while choices:
    if input('Do you want another random number? (Y/N)' ).lower() == 'n':
        break
    print(choices.pop())
```

would give you 100 random numbers without repeating.

If all you need is a random sample of 2, use [`random.sample()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) instead:

```
import random

choices = ['Candy', 'Steak', 'Vegetables']

item1, item2 = random.sample(choices, 2)
```

Comment: Or `random.sample(choices, 2)`

Comment: +1 Random doesn't mean "really random", it just means "hard to tell in advance which number you'll get." A random number generator could (theoretically) return the same result a couple of times just as long as no one could tell *when* this happens.

Comment: ahh, beat me by 2 minutes :) why wasn't your first example to use the more obvious "sample" ?

Comment: @InbarRose: Because the less obvious one is the more interesting option, sometimes? :-P

Comment: For a bit more variety: `heapq.nlargest(2, choices, key=lambda L: random.random())` :)

Comment: @InbarRose: I read the question more as 'given a previous random choice, how do I make sure the next random choice is going to be different?'

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `random` module in Python to do the heavy lifting for you, specifically [`random.sample()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
>>> import random
>>> random.sample(['candy', 'steak', 'vegetable'], 2)
['vegetable', 'steak']
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep the original logic, here is some pseudo code:

```
while(P2Local == A)
   P2Local = random.randint(1,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import choice
x = ['foo','bar','fight']
num_uniq = 2
uniq_rand = set()
while len(uniq_rand) < num_uniq:
  uniq_rand.add(choice(x))
print uniq_rand
```

As @Martijn pointed out, this is not surely not as efficient as `random.sample()` =)

Comment: This picks just *one* value, the OP wanted two. How would you avoid picking the same value twice?

Comment: ;P typo, hahahahaa. kind of