# Why doesn't Python 3.4 randrange want to work?

Tags: python, random

I am currently working on making a small Pokemon game for me and my friends. But to do this, I was going to use the randrange module to randomize which questions were used instead of being in order. I did this, but everytime I run the program, it doesn't do what it needs to do, it just sits at a blank screen. In addition to this, is there anyway that I can make sure it only uses the number once per round? Thanks. Source code:

```
#All importations.
import sys
import os
import time
from random import randrange, uniform
#Clear Screen
def cls():
    os.system('cls')
#The Game
def game():
    score = 0
    possible_score = 20
    print ("In a moment, we will ask you a series of questions relating to Pokémon.")
    time.sleep(2)
    print ("These questions are in no certain order. Answer them the best you can.")
    time.sleep(2)
    print ("Good luck...")
    time.sleep(3)
    while True:
        irand = randrange(1, 2)
        if irand == '1':
            print ("What is the first Pokémon?")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print ("A. Trashbag")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print ("B. Bulbasaur")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print ("C. Arceus")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print ("D. Pikachu")
            time.sleep(1)
            question1 = input ("Your option: ")
            question1 = question1.lower()
            if question1 == 'b':
                score += 1
                time.sleep(1)
                print ("You got it right!")
            if question1 == 'a' or 'c' or 'd':
                time.sleep(1)
                print ("Sorry you answered incorrectly.")
        if irand == '2':
            print ("hai")


#Menu Code
def main():
    print ("Please select an option when prompted!")
    while True:  
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print ("[1] PokéTrivia Test")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print ("[2] Credits")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print ("[3] Exit")
        time.sleep(1)
        menu = input ("Please select an option: ")
        time.sleep(1)
        cls()
        #PokéTrivia Game
        if menu == '1':
            game()
        #Credits go to...
        if menu == '2':
            credit2()
        #Quit the game
        if menu == '3':
            print ("Exiting game...")
            time.sleep(1)
            break 
            SystemExit
#Startup Code
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print ("PokéTrivia!")
    time.sleep(1.5)
    print ("Developed by: Oiestin")
    time.sleep(2)
    print ("In partnership with:")
    time.sleep(1.5)
    print (" /---------\ ")
    print ("| oysterDev |")
    print (" \---------/")
    time.sleep(2)
    cls()
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`randrange()` works just fine, but returns an *integer*. You are testing for a *string* instead:

```
irand = randrange(1, 2)
if irand == '1':
```

Test for `irand == 1` instead. You probably also want to increase the end value; it is *not* included in the possible values. Only `1` will ever be produced otherwise.

Comment: You can also use `random.randint()` if you want to include the endpoint.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Now do you know how to make it so it only uses that integer once per round?

Comment: @oiestin not sure what you mean by that; you already produce a new value every iteration of your `while` loop, albeit that `randrange(1, 2)` will always produce 1. Use `randrange(1, 3)` to also allow 2 to be produced, or use `randint(1, 2)` as its end-point is inclusive.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I only want to use say the number 2 once per round. I don't want it to be repeated during a round.

Comment: @oiestin: define 'round' here. You get to choose when to call `randrange()`; call it once a round and you are fine.

Comment: @MartijnPieters For my game I plan on having 20 questions per play. I only want it to use say question #1 once per play.

Comment: @oiestin: then use `random.shuffle()` to shuffle up all your questions, and take from that list. That way you won't repeat questions.

Comment: @oiestin: also see [Trying to generate a series of unique random numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18722753)

Answer (score 1):

`randrange` will return an `int`.

Then you say

```
if irand == '1':
```

So you are comparing an `int` to a `str`. You can just change the statement to

```
if irand == 1:
```